# RecyclerView selecting wrong item onClick after being scrolled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I have a recyclerviewAdapter based on RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.

```
public class PlaceAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Place, PlaceAdapter.PlaceViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private static final String TAG = PlaceAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

static class PlaceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name;

    PlaceViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    }
}

private Realm realm;
private static RecyclerViewClickListener itemListener;
private TextView lastTextView;

public PlaceAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable OrderedRealmCollection data, boolean autoUpdate, RecyclerViewClickListener listener,
                    Realm realm) {
    super(context, data, autoUpdate);
    this.realm = realm;
    itemListener = listener;
}

@Override
public PlaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.place_item_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new PlaceViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PlaceViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Place place = getData().get(position);
    holder.name.setText(place.getName());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemListener.recyclerViewListClicked(place.getId());
            holder.name.setTypeface(Typeface.create(holder.name.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD), Typeface.BOLD);

            if (lastTextView != null && lastTextView != holder.name) {
                lastTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.create(lastTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL), Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
            notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount());

            lastTextView = holder.name;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getData().size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    final Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            String text = constraint.toString();
            if (text == null || "".equals(text)) {
                updateData(realm.where(Place.class).findAll());
            } else {
                updateData(realm.where(Place.class)
                        .contains("name", text, Case.INSENSITIVE) // TODO: change field
                        .findAll());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            return results;
        }
    };

    return filter;
}

public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {

    void recyclerViewListClicked(int placeId);
}
```

}

the problem is that when I scroll the recycler view, so the top ones are not visible, and I click the view, the view above it gets the bold font. And only if I click it second time my the correct view gets bold typeface.

Comment: I think you forgot to override these method in adapter:
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

   
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. I wonder why these methods have to be overriden

Comment: I faced same problem some time ago and i wasted 2 hour to find that

Comment: That sounds incorrect. That just makes the RecyclerView create as many viewholders as there are items.

Comment: Well it solved my problem so, I marked that answer as accepted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you forgot to override these method in adapter:

```
   @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

I am not sure why this happen, but it is right solution for Recyclerview messing problem when scrolls.

Comment: That makes the RecyclerView create as many viewholders as there are items.

Comment: yes. multiple view type and pagination created using getItemViewType